# Spring jpa check if record exist using String date

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I would like to check the DB if a record already exists for a give run date and name using Spring JPA query using two params:

```
  @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(r)> 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM REQUEST r WHERE r.NAME = :reqName AND r.RUN_DATE = :runDate")
    boolean existsRequest(@Param("reqName") String reqName,
                             @Param("runDate") String runDate);
```

The type of `RUN_DATE` in Database H2, Sql Server is a `DATE` field. Yet I am providing String as param for the date in format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

The above doesn't work for me and I was wondering how to write it correctly using both JPQL and nativeQuery ?

Comment: Just use a data as parameter type!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case, I think the most elegant way is to use query method:

```
boolean existsByNameAndRunDate(String name, String runDate);
```

Comment: Can I omit query ?

Comment: Of course, you can. You can find more detail about query method here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods